# Perl regular expression explanation

Tags: regex, perl

I have regular expression like this:

```
 s/<(?:[^>'"]|(['"]).?\1)*>//gs
```

and I don't know what exactly does it mean.

Comment: If you enter the regexp into http://gskinner.com/RegExr/ and hover your mouse over each piece, it will explain it in a tooltip.

Comment: which part(s) in particular do you not understand?  it helps to know what to explain

Comment: I think the overall intent of that line is to remove all HTML tags from the input.

Comment: @Barmar Thank you very much....That's what I was really looking for :)

Comment: @Barmar except that it should almost certainly be `.*?`, not `.?`; probably a transcription error?  (actually, it should be `.*+`, or it should be `.*?` and the `(?:` should be `(?>`)

Comment: They probably could have just used `s/<[^>]*>//gs`. (Or, equivalently, `s/<.*?>//gs`.)

Comment: @David Knipe: no, the regex is meant to match legal stuff like `<span title=">">` too

Comment: actually, `.*+` is greedy; there isn't a non-greedy possessive form (for obvious reasons - it would always match nothing), so that wouldn't work

Answer (score 1):

The regex looks intended to remove HTML tags from input.

It matches text beginning with `<` and ending with `>`, containing non-`>`/non-quotes or quoted strings (which may contain `>`).  But it appears to have an error:

The `.?` says that quotes may contain 0 or 1 character; it was probably intended to be `.*?` (0 or more characters).  And to prevent backtracking from doing things like making the `.` match a quote in some odd cases, it needs to change the `(?: ... )` grouping to be possessive (`>` instead of `:`).

Answer (score 0):

This tool can explain the details: [http://rick.measham.id.au/paste/explain.pl?regex=%3C%28%3F%3A[^%3E%27%22]|%28[%27%22]%29.%3F\1%29*%3E](http://rick.measham.id.au/paste/explain.pl?regex=%3C%28?%3a%5B%5E%3E%27%22%5D%7C%28%5B%27%22%5D%29.?%5C1%29%2a%3E)

```
NODE                     EXPLANATION
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  <                        '<'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?:                      group, but do not capture (0 or more times
                           (matching the most amount possible)):
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [^>'"]                   any character except: '>', ''', '"'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   |                        OR
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    (                        group and capture to \1:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      ['"]                     any character of: ''', '"'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    )                        end of \1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    .?                       any character except \n (optional
                             (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \1                       what was matched by capture \1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )*                       end of grouping
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  >                        '>'
```

So it tries to remove HTML tags as ysth also mentions.

Comment: It seems that the service is broken. Anyway the result is in the answer.